# Python Backslash followed by Numbers

Tags: python

My understanding of escape keys in python are this:

> They can be used to represent special characters (tab "\t", newline
> "\n", vertical indent "\v")
>
> They can negate quotes/apostrophes ("\"", '\'')
>
> They can negate the backslash escape key ('\\')

But why does `'\1\2\3\4\5\6'` show up as `☺☻♥♦♣♠`?

Why does `'\7'` make a noise on my computer?

And why don't any numbers greater than 7 seem to work for the escape key? Ex. `print('\8')` just shows up as: `\8`

Comment: Additionally, those numbers are written in octal, which is why only 0-7 work.

Comment: The `\000` escape code produces the ASCII character with that octal value,  ASCII 1 is Control-A, ASCII 7 is Control-G, which is the bell.  \015 is Ctrl-M, carriage return.  \012 is Ctrl-J, line feed.  It's exactly like `\x07`, except octal instead of hexadecimal.  All of this was inherited from C.

Answer (score 1):

> The `\000` escape code produces the ASCII character with that octal value, ASCII 1 is Control-A, ASCII 7 is Control-G, which is the bell. \015 is Ctrl-M, carriage return. \012 is Ctrl-J, line feed. It's exactly like `\x07`, except octal instead of hexadecimal. All of this was inherited from C.

*-- [comment](/questions/68978238/#comment121908058_68978238) by [Tim Roberts](/users/1883316/tim-roberts)*